# Transferring large files with WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, system.web

Currently our web service sends files within one web service call. This would otherwise be just acceptable, but because our mobile devices have memory limitations of 40mb, this causes bit of a problem.

Unfortunately I can't modify the server side, so is there any way to enable chunking or streaming of files just by modifying the client? We are using Asp.Net web services (System.Web.Services, .NET3.5), but I'm also interested of hearing a WCF-solution, if that enables it.

Comment: In your current WCF implementation do you use streams or byte array for transfer?

Comment: I think it will be hard if you cant make changes on the server side. How is the endpoint defined right now?

Comment: Well.. we don't have WCF client yet, but that could be an option if it would enable this. The method transfers data in byte array and endpoint is just basic http endpoint with default settings.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this articles:

[Large Data and Streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx)

[How to: Enable a Web Service to Send and Receive Large Amounts of Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa528822.aspx)

There was also an example of  `Web.config` configuration:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxMessageLength="102400"
    executionTimeoutInSeconds="100"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I believe this would also require modifications to the server which is not an option.